# 00:01:30 HMS time if_else condition R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a column which indicates a time stamp:

[1] 00:01:30

[2] 00:02:45

.

.

.

[50] 01:02:05

I want to use these times for IF statments.
I've tried to use `lubridate::hms()`
and it works but it changes the format from:
"00:01:30" to "1M 30S"

I just want the time stamp to stay at the format of "00:01:30" and to use it for conditions.
for example:
`mutate(times = ifelse(timestamp > "00:20:31", 1, 2))`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate( times = case_when(hms(timestamp) > hms('00:20:31') ~ 1, TRUE ~ 2))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  timestamp times
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 00:01:30      2
2 00:02:45      2
3 01:02:05      1
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  timestamp
  <chr>    
1 00:01:30 
2 00:02:45 
3 01:02:05
```